# Missing semi-colon before CTE in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, common-table-expression

Interesting behavior in SSIS.  I have a dtsx package developed in 2005.  One of the Execute SQL tasks have a CTE statement.  It is the only statement in the block.  When I debugged the package in 2005 everything worked fine.  However when I ran the package as a job after deploying to a server, I got an error stating that there was incorrect syntax near the keyword "with."

It worked fine however when I put a semi-colon just before the with statement.  Now I know that previous statements before a CTE need to be terminated with a semi colon and I've got into the habit of always terminating all of my statements anyway... but there were no statements before this CTE.  I even checked any other execute SQL tasks that might have run before and all the statements are properly terminated.  This was a 2005 package running in SQL 2008R2.

So it's working fine now but I'm still left puzzled as to why this happens.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: As you are running the package through a job, I guess some sql queries got executed for executing the job prior to your execute sql task. so you need a terminator before the cte and it is always advisable to use ; before cte.

Comment: Can you use SQL profiler to capture the sql statements being sent while the package is being run?  It would be interesting to see if SSIS puts some other statements in the batch that it sends in an Execute SQL Task.

Comment: Of course.  Good idea Mark.  And Ram, I was wondering the same and yes you're right.  When running as a job, the agent seems to have put these before the CTE in the same SPID. 

1) exec sp_oledb_ro_usrname
2) select collationname(0x0904D00000)
3) ;with myCTE as.....;

     Thanks guys :)

Comment: Might verify you're on the latest and greatest patch for [SQL Server 2005](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com) I used CTEs with 2005 and the only hiccups I encountered was with Lookups with partial cache

Comment: @ScubaManDan, would you mind turning your comment into an answer so it's documented as an answer and so we can vote for it?

Comment: Sure thing Ben.  Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion Mark.  Yes, when running as a job, the agent seems to have put these before the CTE in the same SPID.

1. exec sp_oledb_ro_usrname
2. select collationname(0x0904D00000)
3. ;with myCTE as.....;

So one and two are not terminated, meaning the the third statement (being a CTE) needs to be prefixed with a semi-colon to work.  Somewhat annoying, but ok...